# Upgrading to phpMyAdmin 5.1.2 throws Undefined array key "hide_connection_errors"

Tags: phpmyadmin

After upgrading to this version I received this error: Undefined array key "hide_connection_errors".
How could I solve this?

> Server: MySQL Server (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
>  Tip de server:
> MySQL
>  Conexiune server: Nu se folosește SSL Documentație
> Versiune server: 8.0.26 - Source distribution
>  Versiune protocol:
> 10
>  Set de caractere server: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
>  Apache
> Versiune client bază de date: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.15
>  Extensie
> PHP: mysqli curl mbstring 
>  Versiune PHP: 8.0.15

Comment: There seem to be a new setting that you might be missing if you're using the same config as before you upgraded. https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2022/1/22/phpmyadmin-498-512-and-520-rc1-are-released/ (see the last paragraph under "Security fixes"). Check if there are any upgrade instructions somewhere for this version.

Comment: @M.Eriksson You can put that as an answer. This is a unique question.

Answer (score 3):

This was caused by a problem with the 4.9.8 and 5.1.2 releases. For 4.9, it has already been fixed with 4.9.9, and for 5.2, a new release of 5.1.3 is anticipated soon.

For me, the easiest thing to do is simply ignore the error until the new release, but you could use [the commit](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/48b4ff8247372b61f0fcc2e0b069aa54873e2086) to manually patch your installation.

See also https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17307 and https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17304

Answer (score 1):

[Git Commit link](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/48b4ff8247372b61f0fcc2e0b069aa54873e2086)
This works for me. Simply edit your `config.php` file in `xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes`.

Copy and paste below lines.
At line 1436 ->
`$server['hide_connection_errors'] = $cfg['Server']`
[image]

at line 1509 ->

```
if (! isset($server['hide_connection_errors'])) {
            $server['hide_connection_errors'] = false;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You may have got another phpMyAdmin version. 
In **5.1.2** there is no line with `$server['hide_connection_errors']` in *phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\classes\Config.php*

Your Git commit link does not work anymore.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the broken link. Edited the link now. You can access the link now. 
I am using 5.1.2. Did you follow the xampp update steps?

Comment: Yes, I did that. However there is no config.php as you mentioned. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70962305/1119695 for how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This bug in **phpMyAdmin 5.1.2** has been fixed in this [GitHub Commit](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/17304/commits/b2fa57efa66e23de2b0c1bce63ae5dd9fdb3f262).

Solution: Use the patch or simply modify this file:
*phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php*
Search for 'hide_connection_errors' and add an is-set check two times.

Line 168:
`if (isset($server['hide_connection_errors']) && $server['hide_connection_errors']) {`

Line 215:
`if ($error_number === 1045 && isset($server['hide_connection_errors']) && $server['hide_connection_errors']) {`

In the latest XAMPP release (xampp-windows-x64-**8.1.2-0**-VS16) you may also want to use phpMyAdmin 5.1.2 instead the included one 5.1.1, because 5.1.1 has many PHP 8 warnings.